# array of char assignment does not work

Tags: c++, arrays, char, switch-statement

I am trying to change the value of my char array[10] within a switch statement such that, if we have case 1, my char array[10]="january", or if we have case 2, then array[10]="february" and so on. The problem is that i get error message, and i know that I am doing something wrong. any help will be very appreciated. here is my switch statement written in Dev-C++.

```
char month[10];
switch (i)
{
 case 1:
       month[10]="January";
      cout<<month<<endl;
      break; 
 case 2:
       month[10]="February";
      cout<<month<<endl;
      break;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create strings like `"January"` or `"December"` the compiler is generating a `const char *` which points to a constant array of characters that has a `0` at the end *the integer not the character*.

Your code is trying to assign `"January"`'s address to the 11th element in the array, which it doesn't have because arrays start at 0.

This has a couple problems, First, the elements of `month[]` are characters, not character pointers.  Second, arrays start at 0 so you were looking to use `month[9]`, though that still would have been wrong.

What you are looking to do is copy each character into the array, there are functions that do this like `strcpy` but try it with a `for` loop first to give yourself a better sense of what is going on.

Another way to solve this problem, and probably the way you're after is to change `month` from a character array of a fixed size, to a `char *` that way you can use your earlier method of `month = "January"`  its how I would prefer to do it myself, because it only uses up as much memory as I need and the syntax is cleaner, though you should know how to do both methods.

Answer (score 5):

You can't assign `char` arrays like that, you need to use `strcpy`.

Or better yet, use `std::string`, it's the C++ thing to do.

```
std::string month;
switch (i)
{
 case 1:
       month="January";
      cout<<month<<endl;
      break; 
 case 2:
       month="February";
      cout<<month<<endl;
      break;
}
```

Or if you must stick to `char[]`:

```
char month[10];
switch (i)
{
 case 1:
      strcpy(month,"January");
      cout<<month<<endl;
      break; 
 case 2:
      strcpy(month,"February");
      cout<<month<<endl;
      break;
}
```

The reason you're getting the error is that `month[10]` is a `char`, and you're trying to assign a `const char*` to it, which is illegal. (actually it's undefined behavior, because 10 is beyond the length of the array).

Answer (score 2):

For a quick fix, replace:

```
month[10] = "January";
```

with:

```
strcpy (month, "January");
```

or an equivalent like `strncpy`, if you're one of those types who can't figure out how big their buffers should be - "September", the longest month, will quite happily fit in ten bytes :-)

What the former piece of code is doing is trying to set the *character* at offset 10 of your array to that string, clearly not viable because:

1. You can't fit 8 bytes into a 1-byte bucket.
2. The offset 10 is *beyond* the end of the array anyway.

Of course, an alternative that doesn't use up so many lines in your code could be something like:

```
static char *months[] = { "January", "February", ..., "December" };
if ((i < 1) or (i > 12))
    strcpy (month, "?");
else
    strcpy (month, months[i-1]);
cout << month << endl;
```

---

For a *proper* fix, stop using C-style strings in your C++ code. The designers of C++ put a huge amount of effort providing `std::string` just so you wouldn't experience problems like this.

Comment: Actually, for this assignment, we have to create two versions of the code: one with C-string, and the other one with std::string. Now i see my mistakes, I will fix them. Thanks for your help and time paxdiablo.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign a string literal to an array. You'll have to use `strcpy()` instead.

An alternative way would be to use `std::string` instead of `char` array.

Answer (score 1):

Though it is more a stylistic note, your usage of switch can be vasly improved if you use it in specialized functions:

```
// Using C-string
char const* selectMonth(int i) {
  switch(i) {
  case 1: return "January";
  case 2: return "February";
  ...
  }
  assert(0 && "This is impossible!");
}
```

Then you can use this quite easily:

```
char month[10];
strcpy(month, selectMonth(i));
```

In general, you should find that using small functions help making code more readable. And in true C++ style, you even get const-ness goodness:

```
std::string const month = selectMonth(i); // note: the very same selectMonth!
            ~~~~~
```

This `const` will ensure that you do not accidentally modify your variable afterwards, it only works if you can initialize it immediately, which requires a small function to do the job. Goodness begets goodness :)